# How to leverage the glob method of Filesystem class with StorageFacade?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-5, flysystem

This is concerning **Laravel 5.**

I can see in `Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem` a method called `glob($pattern, $flags = 0)`

Unfortunately, this method is not reflected in the default `FilesystemAdapter` shipped with Laravel 5.

This would be great, due to the fact that I would need to do something like `Storage::disk('local')->glob([_]*[.blade.php]);` (in order to get all stored blade files starting with an underscore.

What is the cleanest way to achieve this?

Comment: If don't you just use `Filesystem::glob()`?

Comment: Using directly `Filesystem::glob()` would not allow using Storage and the config that goes with it... I guess I would need to add a new File Driver (or extend the "local" driver) but this is way too complex...

Comment: Cant you do `Filesystem->disk('local')->glob()`?

Comment: I think the only way to achieve this is extending the FileststemManager, using extend function (you can see this in laravel API: http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemManager.html ($this)).

Comment: Handy yes, but `glob` is excluded from the interface because it's either expensive or untenable on certain filesystems.  That said, @Marcin Nabiałek is likely the best approach.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you cannot run `glob` here, but you could get all files and then filter them, for example:

```
$files = array_filter(Storage::disk('local')->files(), function ($file)
{
    return preg_match('/_(.*)\.blade\.php$/U', $file);
});
```

Of course you need to decide to use `files` or `allFiles` (recursively) depending on your needs. Probably it's not the best solution if you have thousands of files but if you don't it should be enough

Comment: Maybe `allFiles()` if recursive matching is desired.

Comment: As you said this is not the most elegant function. I'd rather use the native php `glob()` function. Thanks anyway Marcin for taking the time to propose :)

Comment: I ended up building a custom file helper class that does not make use of Laravel Dependency Injection Container but that will do the trick for me... @Marcin: anyway, you earned the bounty. ;-)