# How to find file without specific file extension in laravel storage?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, storage

How to find file by name without specific extension in laravel Storage?

like this `"filename.*"`

```
Storage::get("filename.*")
```

I tried this but seems not to work. It searches for specific file with specific extension.

Comment: Try `Storage::get("filename\.*")`

Comment: @RohanKumar Not working for me. I'm using laravel 5.0.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29729863/2286722) is a more general version of this question: how to use glob patterns with `Storage`. As `glob` is not available on every system, `Storage` can not directly implement it (although some transparent wrapper would be very welcome!). The solution is a workaround very similar to [the answer by jedrzej.kurylo here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39072233/2286722): just get the entire list and filter it using RegExp (or some other method).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Storage::get()** takes a file path as a parameter and returns the content of a single file identified by this path or throws **FileNotFoundException** if file can't be found.

Wildcards are not supported in the **path** - one reason for that could be that there might be multiple files that match the path with wildcards which would break the rule that content of a single file is returned from **Storage::get()**. Scanning the whole folder would also be much slower, especially with remote storages.

However, you could get what you want using other functionality that **Storage** facade offers. First, list the content of your storage - that will give you the list of all available files. Then filter the list yourself to get the list of matching files.

```
// list all filenames in given path
$allFiles = Storage::files('');

// filter the ones that match the filename.* 
$matchingFiles = preg_grep('/^filename\./', $allFiles);

// iterate through files and echo their content
foreach ($matchingFiles as $path) {
  echo Storage::get($path);
}
```

Comment: You bit by the buzzer. I was thinking the same solution. Only I got the tweak because of the regex. I removed the ^ to fit my search. Anyways Thank you so much for your time. I'll marked this as correct. Saved my day!

Comment: I feel like this answer is prohibitively expensive in terms of memory if you consider a system that uses an AWS S3 bucket with potentially millions of files from millions of users. I really wish there was a way to ask the operating system of the actual storage disk to do the heavy lifting in terms filtering files in a directory listing using wildcards. :/

Answer (score 5):

Accepted solution works. However I've found this other and I like it more:

```
$matchingFiles = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::glob("{$path}/*.log");
```

See reference here:
http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/143/finding-files-matching-a-pattern

Comment: that reference link is now dead?

Comment: Seems so. That's why responses don't have to rely on external links. Anyway, there you have the code, and you can always look for "Laravel File::glob" for documentation. Check https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php, here https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html and maybe here: https://hotexamples.com/examples/illuminate.filesystem/Filesystem/glob/php-filesystem-glob-method-examples.html

Comment: thanks....seems working for me `\File::glob(\Storage::disk('profile-picture')->path('/')."*.jpeg");`

Answer (score 1):

Minor change to jedrzej.kurylo's answer and combining wogsland's answer using laravel 8:

`'/^filename\./'` or `'/filename\./'` pattern does not work in my case.

> // From:
>
> $matchingFiles = preg_grep('/^filename./', $allFiles);

```
// To:
$allFiles = Storage::disk('yourStorageDisk')->files('folder/path');
$allowedMimeTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/webp'];
$matchingFiles = preg_grep('{'.$image.'}', $allFiles);

foreach ($matchingFiles as $path) {
    // get real mime type
    $contentType = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype(asset($path)));

    // compare it with our allowed mime types
    if (in_array($contentType, $allowedMimeTypes)) {
        // do something here...
    }
}
```

This way we can fetch files or images safely.

Answer (score 0):

Dont trust what you see. Get inside and get the ext for your file

```
$pic = 'url/your.file';
$ext = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($pic));
$ext = explode('/',$ext);
echo $ext[1];
```